# Hide error message on text focus in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-forms

I am beginner of angularjs. I just started on form validation. All is went right until i tried to hide the error message on input focus.

When i am hitting submit button it shows error message. After i focus on textbox it has to hide the error message

And this is my code:

```
  <form name="form" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="7"/>

            <span class="errors" ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.username.$touched) && form.username.$error.required">Please fill username</span>
            <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.minlength">Username too short</span>
            <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.maxlength">Username too long</span>
        </div>
  </form>
```

Please someone help me

Comment: can you describe your problem a bit more? what did you do to "hide" the error message?

Comment: Now i updated the question

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for with the issue?

Comment: Consider using ng-focus https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is just a trick, try if this works :

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="7" ng-focus="focused=true"/>

        <span class="errors" ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.username.$touched) && form.username.$error.required && !focused">Please fill username</span>
        <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.minlength && !focused">Username too short</span>
        <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.maxlength && !focused">Username too long</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

NB : on clicking submit, make focused = false;

Comment: did you try focused = false on submiting ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to mention `ng-app` directive

Answer (score 0):

use ng blur for show instant message on just leaving input field :

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="7" ng-blur="focused=false" ng-focus="focused=true"/>

        <span class="errors" ng-show="(form.$submitted || form.username.$touched) && form.username.$error.required && !focused">Please fill username</span>
        <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.minlength && !focused">Username too short</span>
        <span class="errors" ng-show="form.username.$error.maxlength && !focused">Username too long</span>
    </div>
</form>
```